# Using a static library in C

Tags: c, static-libraries

I found a useful library on github for my project, after building this later I tried to use some predefined function on it. I couldn't compile my project because there is some header file missing like this one :

```
In file included from main.c:2:0:
ptask.h:11:19: fatal error: ptime.h: No such file or directory
```

I compiled my project using this command :

```
gcc main.c -L. -lptask
```

This is all the files in project folder :

```
libptask.a  main.c  ptask.h
```

This is the library content:

```
$ ar -t libptask.a 
pbarrier.c.o
pmutex.c.o
ptask.c.o
ptime.c.o
rtmode.c.o
tstat.c.o
libdl.c.o
dle_timer.c.o
calibrate.c.o
```

Do I need to add all the headers of this files or just link the lib when compiling ?

Comment: that what header are for, you need to include them.

Comment: Your linker doesn't care about header files. What error do you get? What file do you think is missing and why?

Comment: You cannot **compile** code with missing header files.  You can still **link** it into your program.

Comment: the files in the project folder are missing 7 of the header files.  the missing files are: `dle_timer.h` `pbarrier.h` `rtmode.h` `libdl.h` `pmutex.h` `ptime.h` `tstat.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main.c `#include`-s ptask.h which in turn `#include`-s ptime.h. Having compiled static libs alone is not enough (that's the linker's job), you still need to have all used header files (which is the compiler's job), both the ones you use and their dependencies, recursively applicable.

Comment: So what shall I do ?

Comment: Get those header files and tell your compiler where to find them when compiling

Comment: No i just used a simple line of code in order to see if the lib work correctly, I copied the ptask.h header file into my project folder and added it header.

Comment: "you still need to have all used header files (which is the compiler's job), both the ones you use **and their dependencies**"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169362/discussion-between-sendjasni-and-leledumbo).

Answer (score 1):

Normally you need to be sure that the header files are in your "include path", something that a lot of compilers define with `-I` as a command-line option. You'll need to include the source directory of that library, or if it has a `make install` option, then the place where they got installed.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm new with this kind of stuff so would you help me more.
this is the repo link https://github.com/glipari/ptask

Comment: That's the repo, which is of no use to your compiler. You need to specify `-I/path/to/wherever/it/is/src` for those headers to be picked up. This path is local to your computer.

Comment: well, first I cloned the repo in my home directory And I followed all the instruction in the readme, after that I just tried it in order to see if it working but as I specified in the question I couldn't.

Comment: If you got `.o` files out for your project then the compiler succeeded. If it failed you wouldn't get a `.o` output file. You can always make an `include/` directory in your project and copy over the relevant headers.

Comment: I only used this command for compiling `gcc main.c -L. -lptask` but there is no file generated.

Comment: the referenced project 'ptask' has 8 header files.  All 8 of those header files need to be available when creating the library AND need to be available when compiling your `main.c`

Comment: Did you try any of the things I suggested? Repeating the same command over and over won't fix anything.

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
gcc main.c -L. -lptask
```

this is performing the compile step and the link step in one command.

It is also not enabling the warnings, which should always be enabled during the compile step.

Suggest something similar to the following to compile

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -g -c main.c -o main.o -I.
```

and when you have fixed all the warnings, then use something similar to the following to link

```
gcc main.o -o main -L. -lptask
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to compile and execute my code I just have one more question if I may. What is the role of linking with the library if I have to give  the path of all headers files, why I can't just  use the headers file without building and linking the lib ?

Comment: the header files are there to expose each of the functions, etc in the associated library.  If the code is not 'linked' then it will not run.  It is the business of linking to bring in the functions in the library.